# Is there a way to externalize ASP.Identity from webSite to independant WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

ASP.NET Identity as so great features, that I do not want to reinvent the Wheel. 
The only problem is the fact that ASP.Identity is deeply implemented into the MVC website.

Is there a simple way to externalise it into a WCF service and override the existing method to call the webservice instead of having connection to the database directly from our website?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375432/decoupling-asp-net-mvc-5-identity-to-allow-implementing-a-layered-application

Comment: @SteveGreene This is exactly was I have done.
The only problem i have is, how do I make the communication between the public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
and the service.
I think I am missing something, and the solution is very simple.

Comment: Here is another link on decoupling Identity from EF which is not so easy. https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/decoupling-asp-net-identity-2-0-from-entity-framework-in-mvc5-part-1/

Comment: @SteveGreene : This is only the first part, the most important part are not covered.
And this not a strict decoupling because he will create his own UserManager. And, this is exactly what I want to avoid.
The article is from July 2014 :/