# Decoupling Identity from Data layer in Onion Architecture in Dotnet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, onion-architecture

I have an `IdentityDbContext` in my data layer but I can't use and packages form `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. I need to decouple it form the data layer so I can reuse the database context without Identity in a different domain service.

`IdentityDbContext` is inside `Microsoft.AspNetCore`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataLayer.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
        : base(options) { } 
    }
}
```

I want to achieve something like this where I have Dbcontext in my data layer
and later in my web layer I can configure Identity

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataLayer.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
        : base(options) { }
    }
}
```

I had a look at this post but it is about asp.net

[Decoupling ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity to allow implementing a layered application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375432/decoupling-asp-net-mvc-5-identity-to-allow-implementing-a-layered-application)

Is it possible to do this in asp.net core, if yes **HOW?**

Comment: The link you have shared, have you tried that? What the issue you are having with could you please share?

Comment: In that post the accepted answer is using ```Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework``` in data layer which does not answer my question. I want to know if I can decouple identity from data layer & if not I need a concert reasoning, as it makes the data layer restricted for MVC applications which are using Identity, thus reducing reusability.